# Append items in empty list with pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I'm trying to create a filtered dataframe with Pandas and send it to screen with matplotlib split by conditions, but when I try to add items into an empty list, the list is not filtered by conditions, but contains all the elements of csv.

This is the code:

```
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd

plt.style.use('ggplot')
df = pd.read_csv('C:/Users/Gemxs/Documents/Python/Pandas/pokemon.csv')

fig1, (Legendary, Normal) = plt.subplots(nrows=2, ncols=1)

Total = []
gen = []

Leg = df[(df['Legendary'] == True)]
TotalLeg = df['Total']
GenLeg = df['Generation']

Normal = df[(df['Legendary'] == False)]
TotalNormal = df[(df['HP'] < 500)]

for index,row in df.iterrows():
    if ([Leg['Total'] > 500]):
        Total.append(row['Total'])

print(Total)
```

I wanto to send to the empty list only the element that are > 500.

Comment: We don't have access to your csv file, please provide a [mre]

Answer (score 0):

You do not need the loop , you can use [tolist](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.tolist.html) to get values as list:

```py
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv('C:/Users/Gemxs/Documents/Python/Pandas/pokemon.csv')

mask = df['Total'] > 500
Total = df[mask]["Total"].tolist()

print(Total)
```

Answer (score 0):

The loop and conditional statement you're using is not set up correctly to filter these values. Let's fix this.

Here's a revised version of your code:

```
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd

plt.style.use('ggplot')
df = pd.read_csv('C:/Users/Gemxs/Documents/Python/Pandas/pokemon.csv')

# Splitting the dataframe into Legendary and Non-Legendary Pokémon
leg_df = df[df['Legendary'] == True]
norm_df = df[df['Legendary'] == False]

# Filtering Legendary Pokémon with 'Total' greater than 500
filtered_leg = leg_df[leg_df['Total'] > 500]

# Extracting the 'Total' values to a list
total_over_500 = filtered_leg['Total'].tolist()

print(total_over_500)
```

In this code, I've:

Split the DataFrame into two: one for Legendary Pokémon (leg_df) and another for Normal Pokémon (norm_df).
Filtered the Legendary DataFrame (leg_df) to include only those Pokémon with a 'Total' value greater than 500.
Extracted the 'Total' column from this filtered DataFrame into a list (total_over_500).
Remember, when dealing with Pandas, it's often more efficient to use built-in filtering and column selection methods instead of looping through rows with iterrows()

Comment: I tried it and it worked. Thank you for your explanation